# Swift thinks there's an extra trailing closure

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Here's the entire code for a test app, to play with AWS Amplify:

```
import UIKit
import Amplify
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin
import AWSS3StoragePlugin

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let imageKey : String = "house-icon"
    let image : UIImage? = nil
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureAmplify()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func uploadImage() {
        let houseImage = UIImage(systemName: "house")!
        let houseImageData = houseImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!
        
        Amplify.Storage.uploadData(key: imageKey, data: houseImageData, options: nil) {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success( let uploadedData) :
                print(uploadedData)
            case .failure( let error ) :
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func configureAmplify() {
        do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
            print("amplify configured")
        } catch {
            print("couldn't add plugins \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, it throws an error at line 28:

[image]

I'm following sample code, which is here on YouTube:

https://youtu.be/4k2zNLIkHYs?si=5h5-7aQGqZiWvu61&t=278

As you can see, there are no material difference (that I can see) between what's on the screen in the video, and what I have. But, at a second or two past the start Frame of the link. there's a cut, and where he has a compile error that is at the same point as in my code (and persists from the time he adds the code, long enough for the compiler to catch anything); after the cut, the parse error is gone, and the code exactly as shown (as far as I can see), now compiles fine.

So, what the hell is going on? The only material difference seems to be that the sample project is using SwiftUI, mine is UIKit, but I can't see why this matters. It's obviously an async call, but this is the standard Amplify solution, not afaik specific to any UI flavour.... I tried importing SwiftUI to see, but it made no difference, and nothing improved when I moved the code to a generic class, but I think these are red herrings anyway....

The only other thing I can reference is that this tutorial depends on Amplify-ios, which no longer seems to exist, so I used Amplify-swift which has support for current MacOS and iOS, so I think it's reasonable to assume it's a repackaging of what was in -iOS....

Comment: It looks like the api has changed https://docs.amplify.aws/swift/build-a-backend/storage/set-up-storage/ you now use either async/await or combine

Comment: yeah, I just tried rewriting it with a more conventional async approach, and it seems to work. It's quite nice terse syntax he has, and I was just hoping that there was a way to make it work... Thanks for confirming. Here's the currently recommended method: https://docs.amplify.aws/swift/build-a-backend/storage/upload/

Comment: When you have this issue, don't rely on writing exactly what you saw on a tutorial. Comment it, and rewrite it yourself. The Xcode autocompletion should help you navigate with updated methods and their declaration. From there you can see their doc if needed and/or check on migration guides (as with trailing closure, the "terms" are omitted, it might be hard to find them.

Comment: That's good advice, but not what I'm actually doing. But the question was more about how the video went from an uncompilable error to runnable. The video cut is hiding something, but the thing that made it relevant was that it did throw an error at the same point my code did, and then it didn't. I could have been clearer, but when I asked the question, I had it working using the current method: I was just interested in the "alternate" syntax.